# How do I implement a role Based Permission system on a webpage?

Tags: php, html

For a little project I'm doing, I need to restrict user access on my HTML page.

It currently uses PHP, HTML and MySQL database.

What I need to do is have a Admin role and a regular User role, where the website has several tables with data where the Admin will be able to view, edit, remove and add data. While this happens, I only want the regular User to be able to see the tables with no way of messing with them.

I've done some research, but I never found anything for HTML specific pages.

What I've tried was looking up RBAC but I don't know if that is fitting for my kind of problem.

```
<div class="anonymous">
<center><h1>Welcome Anonymous User!</h1></center>
</div>

<div class="end_user">
<center><h1>Welcome End-User!</h1></center>
</div>

<div class="agent">
 <center><h1>Welcome Agent!</h1></center>
 </div>

<div class="manager">
<center><h1>Welcome Manager!</h1></center>
</div>
```

I have found a little bit of this code online, which the mixes it with Js and CSS, however, I am not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: When the user logs in, set a session variable to their role. Then every other script should check the session variable, to see what they're allowed to do. If they're a user, report an error if they try to use an admin-only script.

Comment: In addition to the guidance above, that session variable should also be used to conditionally include/exclude certain HTML elements on the PHP side. You shouldn't use a class to hide unauthorized elements because a savvy user could just disable the css that hides those elements.

Comment: @Romen so essentially, attribute a session variable to both type of users, and exclude the elements I don't want the regular user to touch with PHP code inside the HTML?

Comment: @Pedro Dias, yes. You can simplify that idea by using a single session variable that contains a number/string/value that represents the user role. i.e. `if ($_SESSION["role"] == "admin")` etc.

Comment: @Romen Thank you for the answer! I'll get it running :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is create a session variable for the user. Somewhere in your login code you could put the following:

```php
$_SESSION["user_role"] = "admin"; // if the admin were logging in
```

Then when the user loads a webpage, you can check the session and build the HTML based on the permissions that user has.

```php
<html><body>
<?php
    if ($_SESSION["user_role"] == "admin")
        echo "<p> This text is only visible to an admin! </p>"
    else
        echo "<p> This text is visible to non-admins. </p>"
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was doing this after your initial comment and it works!